# How to Base64 encode a MD5 binary string using shell commands?

Tags: unix, openssl, md5

I need to run this Linux command in Unix (Solaris):

```
echo -n foo | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

But it just gives me an "command not found" error.  I am completely a novice in Unix/Linux so I have no idea if this is even possible or if there is a workaround to arrive at the same result.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

i just executed your command under Ubuntu Linux and it works. Here is the result:

> ```
> $ echo -n foo | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | openssl enc -base64
> rL0Y20zC+Fzt72VPzMSk2A==
> $
> ```

Maybe there is something not installed in your Solaris distribution ? like `openssl`. This command seems good.

Answer (score 0):

`openssl` is not in the PATH.
Look for the location of openssl command (`find / -executable -type f -name "openssl" 2> /dev/null` probably helps).
It may be in `/usr/sfw/bin`, `/usr/bin/`, `/usr/local/bin` or under one of the directories in `/opt`.

Once you find the location, add it to PATH

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sfw/bin
```

or invoke the `openssl` command using its full path.